# Python Script Telnets to Cisco Router... then Blocks?

Tags: python, telnet, cisco

I'm struggling to write a Python script which can log into our Cisco routers and collect the output of simple commands.  The challenge is that not all routers are configured the same way.  When you telnet to some of them, you are challenged for a username & password; other routers challenge you for the password only.  My script must be intelligent enough to tell the difference.

I've written the below code, which is smart enough to realize if the router expects a username or not.  Trouble is, it seems to block ***after*** successfully logging in.  (It works for username/password and password-only routers.)  I've spent the day wrestling with this code, and I think the code blocks when I try to read after sending my simple Cisco command.  (But its also possible that the "show ip int brief" commmand is not being sent.)

Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import telnetlib
import sys


def telnetLogin( host ):
  username = "userguy"                     # Correct username
  password = "password1"                   # Correct password

  flag = 1
  tn = telnetlib.Telnet(host)
  while(flag):
    output = tn.read_some()                # get one line
    if("username:" in output.lower()):     # We are prompted for "Username:"
      tn.write(username+"\n")
    elif("password:" in output.lower()):   # We are prompted for "Password:"
      tn.write(password+"\n")
      flag = 0

  print("======================================================")  # Code reaches here

  tn.write("show ip int brief"+"\n")      # Issue simple Cisco cmd here
  output = tn.read_all()                  # I am blocking here???
  #output = tn.read_until(">", 2)         # This doesn't work either
  print "output ::  "+output              # I never reach this line
  tn.close()

def main():
  host = sys.argv[1]
  output=telnetLogin( host )

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
  print("Program done!\n")
```

Here's the output:

```
[Linux]$ ./telnetToRouter.py RouterA
======================================================
...program blocks here...
```

I can't figure out why I would be able to successfully read/write enough to login in, but then can't do any reading/writing after that.  How do you troubleshoot something like this?

Thanks,
-RAO

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across the answer while looking at my router logs.  It turns out the problem here was a Cisco thing, not a Python thing.  To explain:

When a human admin telnets to a Cisco router and issues a command with a long output, the router will break up the output like so:

```
Router-A#
Router-A# show ip int brief
Interface              IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
GigabitEthernet0/0     10.10.10.100    YES NVRAM  up                    up
GigabitEthernet0/1     10.10.20.100    YES NVRAM  up                    up
GigabitEthernet0/2     10.10.30.100    YES NVRAM  up                    up
GigabitEthernet0/3     10.10.40.100    YES NVRAM  up                    up
 --More--
```

That "`--More--`" is a signal for the human admin to hit the spacebar for more output.  So in actuality, my Python script wasn't blocking - it was hanging because it didn't understand the "more" syntax.

The solution is to have the script issue a "`term len 0`" command ***immediately*** after logging into the router.  This command is Ciscoese for "*print all output in one big block.*"  Once my script did this, it was able to interact with the router, no problem.